# Fatal error: Uncaught exception in zfc-rbac quickstart

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to follow the zfc-rbac tutorial. I got stuck right away. I guess I need to create a service, but the tutorial has no hint about how to create one.

Thanks for your help.

```
module.config.php
---------------
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function($sm) {
            // Create your authentication service!
        }
    ),

),
'zfc_rbac' => [
    'protection_policy' => \ZfcRbac\Guard\GuardInterface::POLICY_ALLOW,
    'guards' => [
        'ZfcRbac\Guard\RouteGuard' => [
            //ADMIN ACCOUNT GUARDS
            'user' => ['admin-master'],
            'user/login' => ['guest'],
            'user/logout' => ['admin-master', 'merchant-worker', 'guest'],
            'user/register' => ['admin-master', 'merchant-admin', 'guest'],
            'user/change-password' => ['admin-master', 'merchant-worker'],
            'user/forgot-password' => ['guest'],
            //CUSTOMER ACCOUNT GUARDS
            'customer' => ['customer'],
        ]
    ],
    'identity_provider' => \RoleBasedUser\Service\AuthenticationService::class,
    'role_provider' => [
        'ZfcRbac\Role\ObjectRepositoryRoleProvider' => [
            'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
            'class_name' => 'RoleBasedUser\Entity\HierarchicalRole',
            'role_name_property' => 'name'
        ]
    ],
    'redirect_strategy' => [
        'redirect_when_connected' => true,
        'redirect_to_route_connected' => 'home',
        'redirect_to_route_disconnected' => 'user/login',
        'append_previous_uri' => true,
        'previous_uri_query_key' => 'redirectTo'
    ],
]
```

---

```
Module.php
-------
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e) {
    $t = $e->getTarget();

    $t->getEventManager()->attach(
            $t->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcRbac\View\Strategy\RedirectStrategy')
    );
}
```

Inside my controller, I have the following

```
AlbumController.php
-----------------
public function indexAction() {
    if (!$this->authorizationService->isGranted('delete')) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'myfetch' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
            )
    );
}
```

The error message I have is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for RoleBasedUser\Service\AuthenticationService' in
>   C:\Users\Sama\Documents\NetBeansProjects\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:550

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) and add an alias to module.config.php as described in [doc](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/07.%20Cookbook.md#using-zfcrbac-and-zfcuser)

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' =>'zfcuser_auth_service'  
    )  
 )
```